# Extract element from output array in a Copy Data activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity that dynamically adds a datetime suffix to the sink file name, which is based on `utcnow()`.  This corresponds to the `start` datetime in the copy data activity. I am looking to extract the 'start' element from the `executionDetails` array in the output:

```
{
    "dataRead": 0,
    "dataWritten": 86,
    "filesWritten": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 0,
    "rowsCopied": 0,
    "copyDuration": 4,
    "throughput": 0,
    "errors": [],
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "FXL",
    "usedParallelCopies": 1,
    "executionDetails": [
        {
            "source": {
                "type": "SqlServer"
            },
            "sink": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFS"
            },
            "status": "Succeeded",
            "start": "2019-08-06T12:29:20.477586Z",
            "duration": 4,
            "usedParallelCopies": 1,
            "detailedDurations": {
                "queuingDuration": 3,
                "transferDuration": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Assuming the activity is called `CopyData`, I want to set the value of `start` to a variable.  I am struggling to get this, a simple `@activity('CopyData').output.executionDetails.start` does not work, telling me to assign an integer value of the `executionDetails` array.  However trying `@activity('CopyData').output.executionDetails[3]` errors telling me the range is (0,0).  I am looking for a method to extract the datetimestamp into a string variable.

I can store `executionDetails` in an array variable, but still unable thereafter to extract the `start` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already worked it out, there range is 0,0 because there is only 1 array in `executionDetails` containing various values.  So, I just need to call the array with `[0]` and then  call the `start` value, so:

`@activity('CopyData').output.executionDetails[0].start`